# Page approval doesn't work from the page

Tags: 2013, workflow, publishing, pages

There are a few similar questions, but our issue is a little different.

Here is the scenario:

A user in the Approvers group (me), edits a page, checks it in, publishes it.
When I approve from the page, generally using the yellow ribbon, I get the workflow approval page and hit approve. Everything looks fine, but the yellow ribbon is still there. Clicking approve again brings me back to the approval page, but it says completed and there are no buttons.

The only way to approve the page is to do it from the pages library, not the page itself.

Once our client's users get in there it'll be very confusing for them.
It is happening to everyone with similar permissions it seems.

Comment: I think I figured it out... will answer the question once I figure I solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like when the Workflow was created, two groups were added to assigned to and parallel was chosen.

When an approval workflow is started, both groups get a task.

I was a member of both groups, but it only counts my approval for one of the tasks. After I approved the first time, one task was completed, and I was only ever brought back to the approved tasked. Seems like a SharePoint bug...

Approving from the library must complete all of the tasks or at least the other one.

To solve this we will probably remove one of the groups from the workflow.

Update: We removed the group and everything is working as expected.